# REST server with dependency injection

Tags: java, web-services, rest, dependency-injection

I like to build a REST server that uses dependency injection. In my case the requirements would be

1) Not the services shall be injected, but the dependency they use

2) The services should be discovered via ServiceLoad and not written predefined in the web.xml

As an example:

I have the following project structure

**project-base**

contains the API, such as *TheServiceInterface* and *TheDaoInterface*

**project-service-plugin**

A plugin - contains a service implementation like

```
Path("foo")
public class TheService implements TheServiceInterface {
    private TheDaoInterface dao;

    @Inject
    public TheService(TheDaoInterface dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("pr")
    public void webmethod(String request) {
        // do something with the request and dao
    }
}
```

**project-integration**

Wiring things together. The idea here is to find all *TheServiceInterface* implementations via *ServiceLoader* and inject the dao implementation into them.

I tried [Jersey and Guice: a perfect combination for writing RESTful APIs](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes//posts/jersey_guice_rest_api), but this uses Jersey 1 and it seems that Jersey 2 and Guice have some problems, or all examples I find is only where the services are injected or written in the web.xml

Is my approach possible - and if so how ? What technologies can be used of achieving it ?

If there is a framework helping or another jvm language like groovy, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: How about Java EE (JAXRS + CDI)?

Comment: thanks - but how can I inject an unknown implementation ? if I look at https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/tests/integration/j-376 or http://coders-kitchen.com/2013/03/29/tutorial-how-to-use-jax-rs-and-cdi-together/ as example - they all use the implementation class in the service, but I like the service to use the interface. And then its unclear how to bind the implementation to the service

Comment: Use Spring Framework. It is perfect for dependency injection. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: With Java EE you can inject interfaces. The binding with the implementation class is done automatically by the container at deployment time; if multiple implementations exist you can use Qualifiers to resolve ambiguities. Have a look at Java tutorials about CDI [https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic002.htm](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic002.htm)